# Existence of map between projective planes.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, projective-space

I'm struggling to solve this problem, any indications would be appreciated.

Is there an application $f : \mathbb RP^3 \to \mathbb RP^1$ of class $\mathcal C^3$ such that $f^{-1}(p)$ is the union of two lines in $\mathbb RP^3$ for all $p\in \mathbb RP^1$ ?

Comment: Hint:  Use Sard's theorem.

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot about this theorem!

Comment: Why don't you write up an answer, then this question can be marked as answered.